# How do I rotate an object around another object with an angle and an offset?

Tags: c++, scene-graph

I made a small game engine with a hierarchy, but have a with problem with applying transform down the hierarchy. I have an object with a parent, and I want the child to rotate around the parent with an offset (the childs `localPosition`, relative to the parent, and a parent rotation).

For example, I have a parent *"Earth"*, and a child *"Moon"*. The *"Earth"* rotates, and the *"Moon"* rotates with a `100, 50` offset.

How do I rotate an object around another object with an angle and an offset?

---

Each object has:

- x / y `localPosition`
- `private` x / y `globalPosition`
- `localRotation`
- `private globalRotation`

This is what I have, so far:

```
float atr = Deg2Rad(parent->GetGlobalRotation());
globalPosition.x = parent->GetGlobalPosition().x + cos(atr) * localPosition.x;
globalPosition.y = parent->GetGlobalPosition().y + sin(atr) * localPosition.y;
```

but it only only on the x-axis if localPositon is `50, 0`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a [rotation matrix](http://cplussplussatplay.blogspot.com.eg/2012/01/2-dimensional-matrix-rotation-simple.html):

```
globalPosition.x = parent.GetGlobalPosition().x 
    + (cos(atr) * localPosition.x) + (-sin(atr) * localPosition.y);

globalPosition.y = parent.GetGlobalPosition().y 
    + (sin(atr) * localPosition.x) + (cos(atr) * localPosition.y);
```

Comment: I think this answer would greatly improve if it didn't rely on a link for the explanation. Maybe you can mention a few things about rotation matrices and why they are the right solution, and then provide the link for people that want to read more about it.